# How can i fix my query that shows me four times each of the products instead of one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to export all the products and some info about them from my mySQL so I wrote the following query

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN descriptions
ON products.product_id = descriptions.product_id
JOIN category_descriptions
ON categories.category_id = descriptions.category_id
```

for a reason, it outputs every product four times. Can anyone help me to find out why?

**Update:** There are only 122 products in cscart_products. The results after this query are 488.

Comment: Could you maybe post your database schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY cscart_products.product_id`

Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM cscart_products
JOIN cscart_product_descriptions
ON cscart_products.product_id = cscart_product_descriptions.product_id
JOIN cscart_products_categories
ON cscart_products.product_id = cscart_products_categories.product_id
JOIN cscart_category_descriptions
ON cscart_products_categories.category_id = cscart_category_descriptions.category_id
GROUP BY cscart_products.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` solves your problem: http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try left join.
http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32

Answer (score 0):

Either a product has several descriptions or categories, or a category has several descriptions, or there are duplicate entries on your database.

Comment: I guess this is true. Can I limit the results to show the 1 of the 4 same products? Maybe to filter it from the ID

Comment: Since you say that `DISTINCT` didn't work, that means that the 4 results are different. Which one do you want? Should the others be in the database?

Comment: Try SELECT MIN(id) or use a LIMIT. You should give more detail though to check if this is adapted to your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me to find out why?

Here's a clue. The wildcard character you are using is used to display all columns/fields. There are **four** tables used in the query. Now we can't be certain of anything as the database schemas haven't been posted.

Comment: I tested it but it didn't make difference. However I think you are right is something on the db schema I didnt notice yet

Comment: Without further detail I can't say for sure but the information in the database should be organized like this: `cscart_products 1<->1 cscart_product_descriptions`, `cscart_products n<->1 cscart_products_categories 1<->1 cscart_category_descriptions`. So each product should have one and only one corresponding description, each category can contain 0 to N products and each category should have one and only one description. The primary ids and foreign ids (from other tables) should correspond.